# Easy way of creating tabs in a Liferay portlet?

Tags: tabs, liferay, portlet

Ello there,

Does anyone know of an easy way to create tabs in a Liferay portlet? Been reading up on it and I just can't seem to find any suggestions on how to do this quite easily.

Would be great if someone that has experience with this could give me some pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Liferay UI TagLib!

First import the TagLib,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
```

Now you can use this,

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="questions,tags,users,badges,unanswered"
    param="tab"
    url="<%= myURL.toString() %>"
/>
```

- The **name** attribute is comma separated with the names of your Tab.
- The **url** attribute will be a URL where the **param** attribute will be appended to as a param.

Alternatively, you can explicitly set the URL for each tab.

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="questions,tags,users,badges,unanswered"
    url1="<%= questionsURL.toString() %>"
    url2="<%= tagsURL.toString() %>"
    url3="<%= usersURL.toString() %>"
    url4="<%= badgesURL.toString() %>"
    url5="<%= unansweredURL.toString() %>"
/>
```

Comment: One more thing Ryan. Where you have to put the URL for each tab. Are the URLs for seperate JSP pages? If my other JSP pages are in the same directory of my whatever_view.jsp , what would the path be to them? Plus what would the data type be for these URLs?

Comment: Are you using Liferay's MVC portlet? Depending on the framework you're using the URL would be different.